# exporting MySql table data to CSV (modify field first)

Tags: php, mysql, csv

i'm using the following code:

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";

$export = mysql_query ( $select ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
    $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";
}

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
{
    $line = '';
    foreach( $row as $value )
    {                                            
        if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
        {
            $value = "\t";
        }
        else
        {
            $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

if ( $data == "" )
{
    $data = "\n(0) Records Found\n";                        
}

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=contagiousbookings.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$data";
```

which works fine BUT i have a date of birth field (field name of dob) which when spat out into the csv shows as 02041950 or something similar. Whats the best way to modify the above code so that it adds a dot between the days month and year i.e: 02.04.1950 or even a / would be great.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What data type is your dob field?

Comment: You'd be much better off converting it to a date field as it's date information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format DATE field with a [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function, e.g. -

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%d.%m.%Y') FROM MyTable;
```

Also, you could use [SELECT...INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) syntax to produce CSV file.

Comment: Can i do that while selecting everything too? Because i need all the fields still not just the dob field?

Comment: Yes, you can do it for every field - SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%d.%m.%Y') AS dob, DATE_FORMAT(dob2, '%d.%m.%Y') AS dob2, DATE_FORMAT(dob3, '%d.%m.%Y') AS dob3...

Comment: so if i want all the fields i would have to call them individually in the select statement? and does the DATE_FORMAT work when its a text field? sorry for al lthe q's! relatively new to this

Comment: @Devart I don't think you can use DATE_FORMAT as the field is a text field

Comment: @Jonn Yes, this has to be called individually, for each field.

Comment: ...And, of course - this method only works for date/datetime fields.

Comment: can i use substring in the select statement? thanks for all your help

Comment: Yes, all string functions can be used in SELECT statement. There are examples - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is to convert the date to a proper date format.
I would do something like this:
- create a new column of DATE type (called dob_new or something similar)
- update the new column with the data

```
UPDATE 
    table
SET
    dob_new = CONCAT_WS('-', RIGHT(dob,4), SUBSTRING(dob, FROM 3 FOR 2), LEFT(dob,2))
```

- then change your original column type to a DATE type
- put the data back into your original column

  UPDATE
      table
  SET
      dob = dob_new
- then drop the new column

You can the use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to extract the date in the format you need (it will naturally come in YYYY-MM-DD format).
Then I would look at using either [SELECT...INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) or PHP's [fputcsv()](http://uk.php.net/fputcsv) function to export the table as csv.